# Help understanding smoothing chokes

Tags: inductor, rectifier

[image: smoothing circuit]

Assume the input voltage is a sinewave. How does the voltage/current across the resistor R change with variance of inductivity L? If I we assume L -> inf, what kind of waveform would we get at the output?

If we assume L is very high that means the inductive reactance is very high, in return the voltage drop across the resistor should be very low.

This is what I got after simulating with L=100H, R=5Ohms and a Vin=10V*sin(wt) with a frequency of 1kHz. Blue is voltage across inductor, green is voltage across resistor, red is current.

[image: ltspice simulation]

so my initial assumption seems to be correct but what does the diode do in this circuit? The current running through the inductor gets cut off abruptly after half a cycle but the voltage seems to be the same wave form as the input up until a point where it goes to zero and stays there until the diode is forward biased again.

How exactly is anything here smoother? From what I understood, I could have used a capacitor parallel to the resistor to smoothe the output voltage (which is what I expected this circuit to do) so why doesnt this circuit do the same?

Comment: You will find LC filters far more effective in filtering HF ripple, and with large values of C even 60 HZ/120HZ ripple is greatly reduced.

Comment: With a very large inductor, the current builds up very slowly to an applied voltage. When the voltage source reverses it's applied voltage so also does the voltage across the inductor, so the diode remains forward-biased still. At some point in time, the inductor's volt-seconds (Webers) goes to zero (no stored energy) and the inductor has no current and cannot any longer sustain a voltage to keep the diode forward-biased. At that moment, the diode becomes reverse-biased until the voltage source goes back through zero and can start the process over. I'm not sure what you expected here or why.

Comment: R can only dampen the effectiveness of an LC based filter. Not sure what your goal is. You do NOT want an LC filter to resonate with the input frequency or ripple.

Comment: The integral of the inductor's positive volt-seconds during the first half-cycle (which is always a diode drop below the supply voltage) must be countered by exactly the same integral of the inductor's negative volt-seconds on the next half-cycle. But since the voltage across the inductor is always a diode drop below the source, this negative-going half-cycle imposes a slightly higher magnitude and so reaches a net zero before the end of the second half-cycle. At this point, the diode blocks. Until the cycle repeats.